# Handle datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've imported datetime in python but can't select a part of them with a for loop.
I used pandas to import a txt file and now I would like to save part of this file in a new variable.

```
date_time= pd.concat((pd.to_datetime(test2018[0]), pd.to_datetime(test2019[0])))
pos= np.concatenate((np.where(data_t == "13-11-2019 00:00"), np.where(data_t == "16-12-2019 00:00")))
lun1 = (pos[1, 0]-pos[0, 0])
assex1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((0, lun1)))
for ond in range(pos[0, 0], pos[1, 0], 1):
  assex1[j] = (date_time[ond])
  assey1[j] = Y[ond]
```

the variable date_time is a timestamp as follows:

(0, Timestamp ('2018-01-01 00:00:00')) (1, Timestamp ('2018-01-01 00:30:00')) (2, Timestamp ('2018-01-01 01 : 00: 00 ')) (3, Timestamp (' 2018-01-01 01:30:00 ')) (4, Timestamp (' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ')) (5, Timestamp ( '2018-01-01 02:30:00')) ...

while Y is a "ndarray":
Y= [0.76 0.75 0.76 0.76 0.75 0.74 0.74 0.75 0.77 0.74 0.74 0.75 0.75 0.76, 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.76 0.75 0.74 0.73 0.72 0.72 0.71 0.71 0.71 0.72, 0.73 0.74 0.72 0.71 0.72 0.72 0.72 0.72 0.74 0.72 0.73 0.74 0.72 0.72, 0.72 0.73 0.72 0.72 0.74 0.73 0.72 0.73 0.73 0.73 0.74 0.73 0.73 0.73, ...]

The for loop does not work.
I don't know how to set a null timestamp and then insert the values in the loop, or if there is a faster way can you tell me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what is it you actually want to do, I mean, in general?

Comment: I want to save part of that data in another variable to then be able to graph the Y data with the relative time data